Markdown mermaid flowchart clickable links-Pdf conversion
I created a flowchart in markdown file using mermaid syntax and then converted it to pdf format. In pdf only flowchart with the contents in it are only appearing. The remaining contents of the pdf are not present. Also the links in the flowchart are supposed to be clickable and should take us to that specific section when clicked. This works well in md file but in pdf format the flowchart is just appearing as a static image.
graph TD;

A[<a href ="#precheck-installation" style="font-size:12px";>Pre-check-Installation</a>] --> B[<a href="#prerequisites" style ="font-size:12px";>Pre-requisites</a>]
B[<a href="#prerequisites" style ="font-size:12px";>Pre-requisites</a>] --> C[<a href="#download-and-extract-CPIO" style ="font-size:12px";>Download and Extract CPIO</a>]
 C[<a href="#download-and-extract-CPIO" style ="font-size:12px";>Download and Extract CPIO</a>] -->  D[<a href="#image-onboarding" style ="font-size:12px";>Image Onboarding</a>]
  D[<a href="#image-onboarding" style ="font-size:12px";>Image Onboarding</a>] 
  -->  E[<a href="#chart-onboarding" style ="font-size:12px";>Chart Onboarding</a>]

The above is my code which is working well in md file. I want the flowchart links to work well in pdf as well. When clicked it should take us to specific sections within the md file as it works in markdown file. Also all the contents present in the file should appear.
I tried the following using which the mermaid flowchart in md file is converted to pdf:

Installed mermaid cli
Executed the following command:
pandoc -F "C:\Users\<Your-Username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\mermaid-filter.cmd" combined.md -o combineddd.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex



